# How to prevent React from posting back when submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In a react component how to prevent it from posting back, so the page will not reload when submit button is pressed.

Below is the component code:

```
const class MyComponent extends React.Component<IEditCampaignStateProps & IEditCampaignDispatchProps, EditCampaignState> {

  ...

  onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    const campaign: Campaign = {
      title: this.state.campaign.title,
    }
    this.props.addCampaign(campaign);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container> 
         ...
      </Container> 
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: use` e.preventDefault()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding one line to your code...

```
 onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const campaign: Campaign = {
      title: this.state.campaign.title,
    }
    this.props.addCampaign(campaign);
   }
```

i have added.. 
      `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thank you, i have found the same answer in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer,

According to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

The preventDefault () method of the Event interface tells the user agent that if the event is not explicitly processed, its default action should not be taken into account as it would normally be. The event continues to propagate as usual, unless one of its listeners calls stopPropagation () or stopImmediatePropagation (), either of which terminates the propagation.

```
onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const campaign: Campaign = {
      title: this.state.campaign.title,
    }
    this.props.addCampaign(campaign);
   }
```